# Python loop not working as intended

Tags: python, python-2.7

After selecting 2 as my choice on the menu, when I input 1 as the option, the program prints "Thanks for using.....Goodbye" and then loops back to the menu instead of stopping. I cannot figure out what the cause is, since I tried numerous times to fix it but failed. Please advise me what to do. Thanks

code: http://pastebin.com/kc0Jk9qY

Sorry I couldn't implement the code in this comment, was becoming a hassle.

Comment: Have you imported the `time` module?

Comment: yes I have imported that module.

Comment: Sorted, look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your code if in a `while n!=1:` loop. Set `n=1` when you want to quit and that's it. So just change your code to the following and it will stop:

```
   elif endex==1:
        print "\nThank you for using RBDC Bin2Dec Converter \nGoodbye"
        time.sleep(1)
        error2=False
        n=1
```

`break` will only terminate the innermost loop, so need to make sure all the outer ones get terminated as well.

**EDIT**
Changed code is:

```
if choice==2:
    while error2:
        try:
            endex=input("Do you want to Exit? \nInput (1)y or (2)n: ")
            if endex== 0 or endex >=3:
                print"Try again"
            if endex==2:
                print "You have chosen to run this programme again...\n"
            if endex==1:
                print "\nThank you for using RBDC Bin2Dec Converter \nGoodbye"
                time.sleep(1)
                error2=False
                n=1
```

Comment: still not working, I tried you suggestion but still doesn't break when option 1 selected and now when I select 2 the program doesn't even loop back.

Comment: Option one as in `choice==1`? If so I haven't changed that one. When `endex==1` the program will keep asking you "Do you want to Exit? \nInput (1)y or (2)n: " as the `while error2` loop will still be running. What else do you want to achieve?

Comment: If you want to go back to the very beginning you need to insert `                  error=False; error2=False` in the `if endex==2` block to re-run the whole thing again.

Comment: This is the local copy of the code I've written based on yours, see if this works for you and, should it not, what you want to change. http://pastebin.com/3gZiMBQS

Answer (score 0):

What you have supplied looks correct. That `break` will break you out of the `while error2` loop. So the problem must lie after that. I expect that `if choice==2` is within another loop, and you are not breaking out of that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is it. Your error2 value is uneccessary. Simply start an infinite loop and break out on valid responses. I would consider doing this in your other loops too.

```
if choice==2:
    while True:
        try:
            endex=input("Do you want to Exit? \nInput (1)y or (2)n: ")
            if endex== 0 or endex >=3:
                print"Try again"
            if endex==2:
                print "You have chosen to run this programme again...\n"
                break
            if endex==1:
                print "\nThank you for using RBDC Bin2Dec Converter \nGoodbye"
                time.sleep(1)
                n=1
                break
```

Comment: He won't be able to stop outer loops easily from within `if choice==2` if he does the same for outer loops. And it leaves no easy control as to which loop to terminate.